# dlopen being called on OS X on Node v0.11 (couchnode 1.2.4)

Tags: couchbase

I used code below to test couchbase

```
 var couchbase = require('couchbase');
 var db = new couchbase.Connection({
     bucket: "default"

 },
 function(err) {
     if (err) throw err;
     db.set('testdoc1', {
         name: 'Frank1'
     }, function(err, result) {
         if (err) throw err;
         db.get('testdoc1', function(err, result) {
             if (err) throw err;
             console.log(result.value);
             // {name: Frank}
         });
     });
 });
```

but it reports

```
/Users/mymac/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:17
      throw e;
            ^
Error: dlopen(/Users/mymac/node_modules/couchbase/prebuilt/win/x64/couchbase_impl.node, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/mymac/node_modules/couchbase/prebuilt/win/x64/couchbase_impl.node: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x90 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at bindings (/Users/mymac/node_modules/couchbase/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:74:15)
    at tryLoadBinding (/Users/mymac/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:13:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mymacg/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:31:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

your comment welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x4d 0x5a` is the file signature of a Windows executable, in other words your couchbase node client install is not for Mac, it's for Windows.

This also seems to be what the path is saying;

```
prebuilt/win/x64
```

This problem may be caused by the node_modules dir being checked into source control on a windows machine and checked out on a mac instead of using package.json to do a local install.

Comment: I executed offcial instalation instruction

Comment: config/autorun.sh
./configure
make install and npm install couchbase, but it still installs the version for windows

Comment: @arachide Adding it to package.json and doing `npm install` or just doing `npm install couchbase` seems to work for me on Mac OS X. Didn't try the other instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this is on OS X 10.9.5 with xcode 6.0.1

Install a fresh copy of libcouchbase:

```
$ brew install libcouchbase
```

This will install libcouchbase into `/usr/local/Cellar/libcouchbase/2.4.1` (or whatever version is current).
Next install Node-SDK via npm

```
$ npm install --couchbase-root=/usr/local/Cellar/libcouchbase/2.4.1 couchbase
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/Users/csun/dev/projects/cashier-api/cashier-api-site/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:17
     throw e;
           ^
Error: dlopen(/Users/csun/dev/projects/cashier-api/cashier-api-site/node_modules/couchbase/prebuilt/win/x64/couchbase_impl.node, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
   /Users/csun/dev/projects/cashier-api/cashier-api-site/node_modules/couchbase/prebuilt/win/x64/couchbase_impl.node: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x90 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00
   at Error (native)
   at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
   at require (module.js:384:17)
   at bindings (/Users/csun/dev/projects/cashier-api/cashier-api-site/node_modules/couchbase/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:74:15)
   at tryLoadBinding (/Users/csun/dev/projects/cashier-api/cashier-api-site/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:13:31)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/csun/dev/projects/cashier-api/cashier-api-site/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:31:17)
   at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

I got the same situation, solved by using node 0.10 instead of 0.12 in my project. Which means your issue could be solved by change node version or couchbase version.

my couchbase version is 
├─┬ couchbase@1.2.4
│ ├── bindings@1.0.0